# How do you call a PHP script as a HTML page load?

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP commands and functions can't generally be executed when in pages with .html extensions. So I'm asking if there are any ways around that. Smart SE users suggested two different approaches: get the server to parse HTML as if it were PHP, or an Ajax technique.

I am retrospectively altering a website that has lots of language translations sitting in sub-directories. Each sub-directory has it's own home page which has a .html extension. Each home page has numerous links from it, many to .PHP scripts. I now want all those satellite scripts to know which home page (i.e. which language version) called them. I have a set of variables to be initialised in a script, one version for each language, one in each sub-directory. So for example in /language/spanish we find init_spanish.php, and so on for other languages. Now, if I was creating this site from new, my index page would be a index.php page, and in it I would include_once the relevant language file. I could rename the index.html file as a .php file but that would create squillions of broken links, plus mess with SEO related factors, and I don't want to edit myself a .htaccess file trying to explain what has moved.

In an ideal world I could simply add a javascript OnLoad event, telling it to call the external init_.php file, which by the way has no output, but does initialise some _SESSION variables. Is there a way to do this, without changing the page's extension from .html to .php? Any Javascript guru's know what runes are required to achieve something like this?

Comment: Yes! What have you tried?

Comment: In an ideal world  ... you would use an CMS for this kind of tasks.

Comment: You could call your PHP script with Ajax allow it to set your SESSION variables. This will not require a page refresh or a reload.

Comment: You could tell your web server to run all html files through the php parser and not do any javascript.

Comment: I would use a simply ajax call to your init_.php. You could pass the value for the particular page via a post variable and handle all of your initialization at that point.

Comment: Hi. Husman and jme both suggest Ajax, but I know less about using Ajax than I can tell you. Can you sketch me an example of what I might try, or point me to an example? Thank you.

Comment: Why would anyone be so arrogant as to mark down the value of this question? It's a real need and I am seeking assistance. Honestly, some people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/your/init_.php",
    data: { language: "EN", someothervariable: "someOtherValue" }
  })
});
```

The values would be in the $_POST array, so to get the language value for example, you would just retrieve it in your php file something like: `$_POST['language']`.

Comment: Thank you jme! That is exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. In fact it goes further; it seems I can set variables from here for PHP, as well as call a file of pre-ordained ones. Thank you so much for this enlightenment!

Comment: Made an edit.  It occurs to me that window on load would happen before jQuery is loaded.